# MYSQL select birthday based on age

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple MYSQL table where I store birthday with the datatype date. Rows:

```
birthday
--------
1989-09-08
```

I want to select users with age 25 years. I use the following query:

```
SELECT birthday FROM `users` WHERE birthday >= now() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR;
```

This should return the above row but because this birthday is more than 25 years and less than 26 years, MYSQL is not returning it. It's returned when I select `INTERVAL 26 YEAR`

Is there a more correct query to use?

Comment: try birthday>=date_sub(curdate(),interval 25 year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the comparison backwards.  You want:

```
WHERE birthday <= now() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR;
```

For a range, use:

```
WHERE birthday <= now() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR and
      birthday > now() - INTERVAL 26 YEAR
```

Comment: How can I select a range of 18 years to 25 years? I tried the range but it lead to the same problem

Comment: You would replace "25" with "18 in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

For range you also use BETWEEN, put the earliest date first

```
WHERE birthday BETWEEN 
    CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 26 YEAR + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 18 YEAR
```

Another way, but not recommended with big data

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, birthday) BETWEEN 18 AND 25
```